# Are some (not all) users closing questions for not being clear just because they don't know the answer?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Are some (not all) users closing questions for not being clear just because they don't know the answer?

From the comments [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/408486/can-labour-be-used-literally-for-the-materials-that-need-to-be-worked-upon), I think that's what's happening there. I think it  a very interesting case of cognitive dissonance, rather than any form of self involvement, though.

Cheers.

Comment: No: you have assumed that synonymity can be extended indefinitely.  "*labour* means *work*, and *work* can (according to google definitions) mean the **materials you use at work,**" so *labour* can mean the *materials you use at work*. That's not the case; it's stretching the synonym too far.

Comment: @AndrewLeach and that makes the question un-understandable *how* ?

Comment: and obviously i haven't assumed synonymy can be extended "indefinitely"

Comment: It makes the question unanswerable, because the question is invalid; it's based on an incorrect premise.

Comment: @AndrewLeach but nowhere do i imply that it can be extended "indefinitely". i think in this instance, you would close because the question is too easy? i'm not clear on your reasoning here, tbh

Comment: No, if I were to close it, it's because it's unanswerable because it's based on an incorrect premise. See my first comment. A=>B and B=>C does not imply A=>C.

Comment: @AndrewLeach it's not based on an incorrect premise! you misunderstand the nature of inference. where do i say anything about "infinite" extension, where do i even *seem* to imply that? i ask about one inference, not an *infinty* of them. i am disappointed that you are so wrong about this, yet are happy to willfully vote

Comment: @AndrewLeach As I see it, the transitive relation isn't the premise - it's actually the question, or at least the rationale the OP wants validated or invalidated.

Answer (score 3):

I honestly understood the question quite clearly. It's an interesting one imho. It's unclear to me what's unclear in it. Maybe it's because I'm a non native speaker that I understood OP's thought process.

If the answer to it is "no, you're sadly mistaken, and here's why...", then that's a valid answer. And that's a valid on topic question as well.

If it wasn't asked, how would OP know an answer to it?

(EDIT: It slipped my mind that you're the OP. So you have schizophrenia, you say. So that might explain why you can't think as clearly as a native speaker usually does. I hope Edwin's partial answer was helpful to you. I've preserved it in a CW just in case.)

Comment: incidentally, thank you. i am an EL native, i just had to relearn how to read and write, in my early 20s. cheers

Comment: @user3293056 So you're a native, ha! I wonder how you thought up a question like this. It's not supposed to even come to a native's mind, I think. :)

Comment: my friend. exactly what i said. i speak schizophrenia

Comment: no offence meant... but yes. we shall feast on their lungs, on their heart, and on their brain. i'm deleting all accounts, i do not need to be misunderstood. thank you, and good luck ha

Comment: @user3293056 that's a very rash decision. Account suicide solves nothing.